# What is in clojure.lang?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to figure out the difference between clojure.lang and clojure.core.

For instance, the in-ns function is in clojure.lang

```
> in-ns
=> #< clojure.lang.RT$1@bc647a2>
```

But the create-ns function is in clojure.core

```
> create-ns
=> #<core$create_ns clojure.core$create_ns@6945af1f>
```

And while I can do ns-interns on clojure.core, to know what belongs to it

```
> (ns-interns 'clojure.core)
=> {sorted-map (var clojure.core/sorted-map), ... }
```

It won't work with clojure.lang

```
> (ns-interns 'clojure.lang)
Exception No namespace: lang found  clojure.core/the-ns (core.clj:3760)
```

And unfortunately, in the documentation, *everything* appears as if it was part of clojure.core
([example1](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core), [example2](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/in-ns))

Now, I am trying to implement a new language on top of clojure.lang, so I used create-ns to get a namespace that doesn't have clojure.core (but it does have clojure.lang, which makes sense). But then I wanted to know what clojure.lang had, and I couldn't figure out what was in clojure.core vs clojure.lang.

So what is in clojure.lang?

EDIT:

As cgrand shows below, it happens that in-ns is also part of the clojure.core namespace. But that doesn't tell what I wanted to know.

Which is: when I make a new empty namespace with (create-ns 'name-of-namespace), which functions and macros are defined in it?

Comment: that's an easier question -- a new namespace will contain references to **all** of `clojure.core`, except those parts marked private or which your `ns` declaration explicitly requested not be imported.

Comment: That is not quite true. Even if I explicitly request that *nothing* is imported, some symbols still will be. (for instance in-ns)

`> (ns foobar( :refer-clojure :only []))
=> nil

> print
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: print in this context, compiling:(/home/bruno/.IdeaIC13/system/tmp/form-init2391774383162462208.clj:1:1442) 
> in-ns
=> #< clojure.lang.RT$1@7f806d54>` In this example print was not imported, but in-ns was. I would like to know exactly which symbols are imported.

Comment: It does make sense that this is like this. Now, what I am trying to do, is make my own programming language on top of clojure. That means, for instance, that the symbol * should point to my own product function, not clojure's. But I still want some of the features of the language. But I see that at least some symbols will be imported no matter what (which make sense, for instance, if in-ns was not imported, I would get stuck in the namespace as soon as I declared to be in it). I want to know which.

Comment: No, you wouldn't be stuck even without `in-ns` referred -- you could still refer to `clojure.core/in-ns`.

Comment: Ah, that is a good point. So, is it possible to make sure that NO symbol whatsoever is interned in the new namespace? That would solve my issue, even if it didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

`clojure.lang` is a java package containing implementation classes for Clojure.

`clojure.core` is the clojure namespace defining the core of the language.

When you see `#< clojure.lang.RT$1@bc647a2>` it just means that `in-ns` holds something that is anonymously defined in `clojure.lang.RT.java`. However:

```
=> (meta #'in-ns)
{:added "1.0", :ns #<Namespace clojure.core>, :name in-ns, :doc "Sets *ns* to the namespace named by the symbol, creating it if needed.", :arglists ([name])}
```

demonstrates that `in-ns` belongs to `clojure.core`.

Comment: I see, so it is in the clojure.core namespace. But when I create a new namespace, certain functions in clojure.core will be there, but not all of them. How do I find out exactly which functions these are?

Comment: @BrunoLoff if you create the namespace with `(ns foo)` all public vars of `clojure.core` are referred into it (you can exclude some using `:refer-clojure` in `ns`). However `in-ns` is for chnging the current namespace, not really creating a new usable namespace -- it's more like `cd` but sometimes acts as `mkdir -p` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all symbols defined in a namespace by using ns-map.
That will show all symbols defined in a namespace.

```
    `(keys (ns-map 'namespace))`
```

To show all functions (not macros) in a namespace.

```
    `(filter #(ifn? %) (keys (ns-map 'namespace)))
```

Comment: Hmm that actually gets me everything in java.lang, but nothing in (the java class or whatever) clojure.lang. >>> `(create-ns 'foo)
=> #<Namespace foo>` >>> `(keys (ns-map 'foo))

=> (ProcessBuilder Enum SuppressWarnings Throwable InterruptedException ...)`

But if I evaluate, say, in-ns, it still shows that it is bound to something. Maybe clojure has no reflection for this aspect?

Comment: Here is something else that is weird:
>>> `(create-ns 'foo) => #<Namespace foo>` >>> `(in-ns 'foo)
=> #<Namespace foo>`
>>> `(clojure.core/meta 'in-ns)
=> nil` >>> `in-ns
=> #< clojure.lang.RT$1@1a8cc3ba>`

Comment: So `(create-ns 'foo)` just creates the namespace, it doesn't import anything. If you try `(in-ns 'foobar)` and the "foobar" namespace doesent exist, Clojure will create one for you and put you inside of it. From there, only the namespace exists and you must refer clojure.core. `(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)` will import all the  functions that come with clojure.core and refer the symbols to the namespace.